# D8 override core class

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

I am using [SHS](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs) module. What I want to do is, override the SHS widget such that the I can alter the query used to fetch the data in the widget. Till now, I have overriden the route controller and have found that the underlying query is being generated from the `loadTree()` function of the  `core/modules/taxonomy/src/TermStorage.php` file.

Now what basically I want is, to override this function, such that I may be able to alter the query to my requirement. Im not sure what is the correct way to do that in OOPS.

Please help.

Comment: Using `hook_query_alter` might be a lot easier

Comment: Good idea, but, I want to send a parameter to this query based on which another condition will be added. I dont think that is possible to do with `hook_query_alter`.